# RoR: How to remove brackets from an array?

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails

I have this array:  `my_array = ["1", "2", "3"]`

How can I remove the brackets?

My desired output, also replacing the double quotes with single quotes, is `'1','2','3'`

ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
puts "'" + my_array.join("','") + "'"
```